# haskell use file argument from command line with ".."

Tags: haskell, haskell-cmdargs

Using [`a command line parser`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative) gives a string containing a filename argument, which in this case is "../somedir". How to convert this string into a typesafe `Path Rel Dir` from [`Path`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/path-0.9.2) to combine later with the current directory?

```
relDir1 <- parseRelDir fp
```

throws an error (as indicated in the [description](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/path-0.9.2/docs/Path-Posix.html#g:4), because it "contains a .. path component representing the parent directory")

Trying to combine the currentDir with the String from the command line first, as in

```
relDir2 <- parseRelDir (currDir </> fp)
```

returns the same error.

I found a "hack", using `collapse` from [FileSystem.Path](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/system-filepath-0.4.14/docs/Filesystem-Path.html#t:FilePath), which requires an `decodeString` and a `encodeString` to convert from String (aka FilePath) to the special `FilePath` used:

```
combPath = toFilePath currDir </> (locationDir $ flags) :: FilePath 
collPath = collapse . decodeString $ combPath   
absdir = makeAbsDir . encodeString $ collPath :: Path Abs Dir
```

but assume there is somewhere a better approach to this common task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You linked to the documentation of the Path package. There are 6 mentions of `..` if you search that page, and one of them is clearly [addressing your question](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/path-0.9.2#accepting-user-input):

> Sometimes you have user input that contains `../`. The solution we went
> with is to have a function like [`resolveDir`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/path-io-1.8.0/docs/Path-IO.html#v:resolveDir) (found in path-io package):
>
> ```
> resolveDir :: (MonadIO m, MonadThrow m)
>            => Path Abs Dir -> FilePath -> m (Path Abs Dir)
> ```
>
> Which will call canonicalizePath which collapses and normalizes a path and then
> we parse with regular old parseAbsDir and we’re cooking with gas. This
> and others like it might get added to the path package.

Comment: I did not understand the information in the Path package. With the added information about `canonicalizePath` I saw that `absdir <- resolveDir currDir (locationDir flags)` produces the desired result!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you are looking for [`canonicalizePath`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.8.1/docs/System-Directory.html#v:canonicalizePath). Starting ghci in `/home/<my-user>`:

```
System.Directory> canonicalizePath ".."
"/home"
```